# Load XML from form field?

Tags: php, xml, get

I have a code that parses XML like this

```
 $xml->load("https://mywebsite.com/api.php");
```

I have a hidden field that has the url above in a hidden field(curl_url_string) already how would I load the XML based off that field?

like this? or similar

```
$xml->load('$curl_url_string');
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Note that it is generally considered unsafe to pass user input urls directly to a load function like that, without checking its validity

Comment: It already checks to make sure of that, I just need to pass that value on the final submit

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents("http://example.com/webservices/xml.php")
... // do $xmlString validations here
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is terribly dangerous, since the end-user could change what URL gets loaded, so proceed at your own risk.

To make your code work as-is, this should do the trick:

```
$curl_url_string = $_REQUEST['curl_url_string'];
$xml->load($curl_url_string);
```

Depending on what form method you use (GET vs POST), you can use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` (which contains the contents of both `$_GET` and `$_POST`)

A better way to do this would be to have a list of valid URLs, and reference them in your hidden field; something like:

```
$curl_url_strings = array(
    "api1" => "https://www.example.com/api1.php",
    "api2" => "https://www.example.com/api2.php"
);

$curl_url_key = $_REQUEST['curl_url_key'];

if(array_key_exists($curl_url_key, $curl_url_strings)) {
    $curl_url_string = $curl_url_strings[$curl_url_key];
    $xml->load($curl_url_string);
} else {
    // Invalid URL key provided - show an error?
}
```